# How to check the git hash of a pip-installed package

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Is there any handy way to check the git-hash of a pip-installed package?

For example, I install a package from github by specifying its commit hash:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/user/some-repository@[git-commit-hash]#egg=package-name
```

After writing code & doing some experiments, I forget which version I pip-installed.
At least
`pip show --verbose package-name` doesn't provide any info about git commit hash.

Comment: Nop, no way. It would be better if you would have installed the package using `requirements.txt` from which you could later find out versions, tags, branches or commit hashes.

Comment: @phd in case it is a submodule - yes - we have a `requirements.txt`. But what we can do if we are installing the tool?

Comment: @denys In what way it's different? A "tool" is a script (or set of scripts) + the library (or set of libraries). You install it it with `pip`? Then you should create, use and save `requirements.txt`.

Comment: @phd it seems I've got you... Are you suggesting to create a separate `requirements.txt` file (without any project) to just install that tool?

Comment: @denys Not only that — I also suggest to put exact version to install; not just `pip install sometool` but `pip install sometool==1.3.2`. For installation from VCS I recommend to record an exact hash or tag, not branch (branches move). This way you record and archive exact version numbers so you can reproduce installation later any time any place.